# How do I Pass value from URL

Tags: vb.net, parsing

Morning,
Hi, I get stuck on how to parse a value as parameter from one page to another.
Here what I've already done

On Functional.aspx.vb, I parse value to Functional_Sub.aspx from URL

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

            html.Append("<a href='Functional_Sub.aspx?flag=" + row(0) + "'>IKUTI</a>")

        Next
```

What I get is
'Functional_Sub.aspx?flag=FUNCP-000001' in URL

On Functional_Sub.aspx.vb I try to get parsed value with

```
Dim flag As String = Request.Params("flag")

Private Function GetData() As DataTable
    Dim Connbackbone As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BackboneConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(Connbackbone)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT a.[IDFuncChild], b.[IDFuncParent], a.[nmSubKat] FROM [EL_MstFunctional_SubKat] a inner join [EL_MstFunctional_Kat] b on b.[IDFuncParent] = a.[IDFuncParent] where IDFuncParent = @IDFuncParent order by b.IDFuncParent, a.IDFuncChild")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDFuncParent", flag)
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    Return dt
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

But I get this result
Request is not available in this context
Please guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be after the page is generated.

```
Dim flag As String

Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    flag = Request.Params("flag")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @mukai . I already placed in page_load but still returning me an error "Request is not available in this context"